# cv2.counterArea doesn't work anymore in OpenCV 4.0

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to extract a hand out of an image. I am using OpenCV 4.0 and Python 3.6.

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresholded.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # return None, if no contours detected
    if len(cnts) == 0:
        return
    else:
        # based on contour area, get the maximum contour which is the hand
        segmented = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

And it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 85, in <module>
    hand = segment(gray)
  File "test.py", line 37, in segment
    segmented = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'contour'
```

Since that worked like half a year ago, I am assuming that the error occurs because of some kind of a module change. How can that be fixed?

Comment: Good question for their GitHub: https://github.com/opencv/opencv

Comment: Well in mean i think that im Just Not knowing the right Line To fix the Problem . Not that Theres Something wrong with the module.

Comment: Yup, but this kind of question you will get addressed there. Also - I like your humility, yet backwards compatibility or its lack might be a design decision, which is best to be answered by the author(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pay attention to the outputs of [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). For any OpenCV version >= 4.0, it's

```py
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)
```

I made up an example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up dummy image
image = np.zeros((400, 400), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(image, (150, 250), 100, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# Find contours: OpenCV 4.x
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

if len(cnts) == 0:
    # return None, if no contours detected
    segmented = None
else:
    # based on contour area, get the maximum contour which is the hand
    segmented = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

print('Number of contour points:', segmented.shape[0])
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The example image looks like this:

[image]

The output:

```
Number of contour points: 292
```

Hope that helps!